# Mesh Decimate on certain areas only

Tags: modeling

i want to use decimate only on certain areas of a mesh - or better explained control the level of decimation with another object.

Imagine a plane with quite high polygon-count. Now i create sphere - it's size and position should control how much reduction is applied.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options can be **Decimate** modifier with **Dynamic Paint** ...

[image]

In this example:

- **Plane** - enable *Dynamic Paint* under *Physics Properties*, set as **Canvas**, *Vertex*, *Dssolve* 1, *Slow* OFF, *Output* click on plus icon (this creates vertx group storing weight data)
- **Sphere** - enable *Dynamic Paint* under *Physics Properties*, set as **Brush**
- add *Decimate* modifier to *Plane* and choose "dp_weight" as vertex group, *Ratio* here 0.5.

Note: My anim displays Cube and not a Sphere because I set represent Sphere in Viewport as Bounding Box to better see final result.

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot. Very helpful!

Comment: Great. If the answer solved your issue consider mark answer as accepted by clicking on check mark under vote arrows, so others can easily see Q was answered from Q list. You can undo it any time. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour